# Import json file into Blade Template

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-blade

This might be silly. I simply need to import a `dummydata.json` file into a blade template to loop over in my `file.blade.php` but I can't find any resources on how to do this.

Comment: open the file and then `json_decode` the contents ... where is this file located?

Comment: @lagbox Thanks for the quick response. The file is located directly next to the blade template - same directory.

Comment: i would probably move that file into the `storage/app` directory somewhere as that is the root of the "local" disk for the storage system and your json file isn't a view ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: I'm having trouble opening the file using Blade syntax. Have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the structure of the JSON file so I wouldn't know what you are trying to iterate, but you can retrieve the data using the Storage system and `json_decode` the file contents to get something usable (assuming the file is in `storage/app` and your default disk is 'local' [which is the default]):

```
$contents = Storage::get('dummydata.json');

$data = json_decode($contents);

return view(..., ['contents' => $data]);
```

Then in your view `$contents` would be the decode JSON, what ever it may be.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - File Storage - Retrieving Files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#retrieving-files)